# Android Emulator with proxy: "@" in the password?

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, http-proxy

According to Android documentation:

If your emulator must access the Internet through a proxy server, you can use the -http-proxy  option when starting the emulator, to set up the appropriate redirection. In this case, you specify proxy information in  in one of these formats:

```
http://<machineName>:<port>
```

or

```
http://<username>:<password>@<machineName>:<port>
```

What if my password contains the special caracter "@" ????

Answer (score 1):

Try urlencoding the "@" in the password to `%40`.